# Why does my code only check for an if statement once and then stop?

Tags: processing

I am currently working on a game in Processing and I have split it up into 3 parts so far. The start screen, the level selection screen, and the game screen. The start screen seems to be working fine but when the user gets to the level selection screen it only checks for an if statement once and then stops. Here is the relevant code:

```
int level = 0;
Player myPlayer;
Floor[] level1Floors = new Floor[5];
Selector levelSelector1;
Selector levelSelector2;
Selector levelSelector3;
Selector levelSelector4;
Selector levelSelector5;
Selector levelSelector6;
Selector levelSelector7;
Selector levelSelector8;
Selector levelSelector9;
Selector levelSelector10;


void setup () {
 size(800, 600);
 myPlayer = new Player(width/2, 500, 50, 50, 15, 0, 9, true, false, false, false, false);
 level1Floors[0] = new Floor(0, 525, width);
 level1Floors[1] = new Floor(width, 485, width/2);
 startButton = loadImage("playButton.png");
 startButtonHover = loadImage("playButtonHover.png");
 star = loadImage("Star.png");
 starUnlit = loadImage("StarUnlit.png");
 levelSelector1 = new Selector(1, 110, 210);
 levelSelector2 = new Selector(2, 255, 210);
 levelSelector3 = new Selector(3, 400, 210);
 levelSelector4 = new Selector(4, 545, 210);
 levelSelector5 = new Selector(5, 690, 210);
 levelSelector6 = new Selector(6, 110, 390);
 levelSelector7 = new Selector(7, 255, 390);
 levelSelector8 = new Selector(8, 400, 390);
 levelSelector9 = new Selector(9, 545, 390);
 levelSelector10 = new Selector(10, 690, 390);
}

void draw () {
 if (gamestate == 0) {
   startScreen();
 }
 if (gamestate == 1) {
   println("eh");
   levelSelection();
   levelSelector1.displaySelector();
   levelSelector2.displaySelector();
   levelSelector3.displaySelector();
   levelSelector4.displaySelector();
   levelSelector5.displaySelector();
   levelSelector6.displaySelector();
   levelSelector7.displaySelector();
   levelSelector8.displaySelector();
   levelSelector9.displaySelector();
   levelSelector10.displaySelector();
 }
 if (gamestate == 2) {
   if (level == 1) {
     background(54);
     level1();
   }
 }
}
void collision () {
 int trueY = myPlayer.y + myPlayer.yOffset;
 if (trueY > level1Floors[0].y) {
   myPlayer.y = level1Floors[0].y - myPlayer.yOffset;
   myPlayer.yvel = 0;
   myPlayer.flag = false;
 }else {
   myPlayer.yvel++;
 }
}

void keyPressed () {
 if (key == ' ' && !myPlayer.flag && gamestate == 2) {
   myPlayer.isJump = true;
 }
 if (key == 'a' && myPlayer.left == false && gamestate == 2) {
   myPlayer.left = true;
 }
 if (key == 'd' && myPlayer.right == false && gamestate == 2) {
   myPlayer.right = true;
 }
 if (key == 'g') {
   exit();
 }
}
void keyReleased () {
 if (key == ' ') {
   myPlayer.isJump = false;
 }
 if (key == 'a') {
   myPlayer.left = false;
 }
 if (key == 'd') {
   myPlayer.right = false;
 }
}

class Floor {
 int x1;
 int y;
 int x2;

 Floor (int tempX1, int tempY, int tempX2) {
   x1 = tempX1;
   y = tempY;
   x2 = tempX2;
 }

 void display () {
   strokeWeight(3);
   line(x1, y, x2, y);
 }
}

------------- this code is in a different tab ----------------
PImage star;
PImage starUnlit;
int starSize = 75;

void levelSelection () {
 background(130);
}

class Selector {
 int value;
 int x;
 int y;
 int sizeX;
 int sizeY;
 int radius;
 int fillValue;
 int strokeValue;

 Selector(int tempVal, int tempX, int tempY) {
   value = tempVal;
   x = tempX;
   y = tempY;
   sizeX = 120;
   sizeY = 120;
   radius = 20;
   fillValue = 70;
   strokeValue = 55;
 }

 void displaySelector () {
   fill(fillValue);
   stroke(strokeValue);
   strokeWeight(6);
   rectMode(CENTER);
   rect(x, y, sizeX, sizeY, radius);
   fill(255);
   textSize(40);
   textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
   text(value, x, (y-20));
   imageMode(CENTER);
   image(starUnlit, (x - 30), (y + 20), starSize, starSize);
   image(starUnlit, x, (y + 30), starSize, starSize);
   image(starUnlit, (x + 30), (y + 20), starSize, starSize);

   if (mouseX > (x - 60) && mouseX < (x + 60) && mouseY > (y - 60) && mouseY < (y + 60)) {
     println("wow ur computer is a potato");
     sizeX = 130;
     sizeY = 130;
     fillValue = 90;
     strokeValue = 75;
   }else {
     println("u succ");
     sizeX = 120;
     sizeY = 120;
     fillValue = 70;
     strokeValue = 55;
   }

   if (mouseX > (x - 60) && mouseX < (x + 60) && mouseY > (y - 60) && mouseY < (y + 60) && mousePressed) {
     gamestate = 2;
     level = value;
   }
 }
}

------------ this is also in a different tab idk if it is relevant though ---------------
PImage startButton;
PImage startButtonHover;
int startButtonx = 400;
int startButtony = 350;

void startScreen () {
 background(130);
 imageMode(CENTER);
 image(startButton, startButtonx, startButtony, 100, 100);
 textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
 textSize(60);
 text("OBJECTIVE: BREAK OUT", width/2, height/6);

 if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, startButtonx, startButtony) < 43) {
   imageMode(CENTER);
   image(startButtonHover, startButtonx, startButtony, 110, 110);
 }
 if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, startButtonx, startButtony) < 43 && mousePressed) {
   gamestate = 1;
 }
} 

void level1  () {
 background(54);
 myPlayer.display();
 level1Floors[0].display();
 level1Floors[1].display();
 collision();
 myPlayer.jump();
}

class Player {
 int x;
 int y;
 int vSide;
 int hSide;
 int yOffset;
 int speed;
 int yvel;
 int xvel;
 boolean isCollide;
 boolean isJump;
 boolean right;
 boolean left;
 boolean flag;

 Player (int tempX, int tempY, int tempVSide, int tempHSide, int tempSpeed, int tempyvel, int tempxvel, boolean tempIsCollide, boolean tempIsJump, boolean tempRight, boolean tempLeft, boolean tempFlag) {
   x = tempX;
   y = tempY;
   vSide = tempVSide;
   hSide = tempHSide;
   speed = tempSpeed;
   yvel = tempyvel;
   xvel = tempxvel;
   isCollide = tempIsCollide;
   isJump = tempIsJump;
   right = tempRight;
   left = tempLeft;
   flag = tempFlag;
   yOffset = 25;
 }

 void display() {
   fill(0);
   strokeWeight(2);
   stroke(255);
   rectMode(CENTER);
   rect(x, y, hSide, vSide);

   y += yvel;
 }

 void jump () {
   if (isJump) {
     y -= 20;
     flag = true;
   }
   if (left && x >= 25) {
     x -= xvel;
   }
   if (right && x <= (width - 25)) {
     x += xvel;
   }
 }
}
```

I know the code is pretty disorganized and Im planning on fixing the problem later. The problem lies in the Selector class if I am correct as that is where the 2 if statements are that don't keep checking if the condition is met. Any help would be appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: There's a lot of code missing to be a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I lobotomized it until it ran and it did pretty well. I could choose a level with no obvious issue. A code snippet which displays the problem and can be run on it's own could help us find the issue, and also the description of the current behavior of the program versus the desired behavior (what you said helps but could be more precise). Also, FYI, tabs in Processing doesn't change anything, the compiler acts as if everything was in one huge tab.

Comment: Thank you for responding! What you mentioned is exactly what I am trying to figure out. I don'd know where the problem is I just know that the if statements under the class Selector are only checked once when I run it and I don't know why. To add to the problem if I don't change anything the code works fine sometimes but most of the time it doesn't. At this point I am starting to think it might be my computer.

Comment: Ok, let me ask a different question then: why would these `if` be checked more than once? Is it because the `draw()` loop stalls after one iteration, or because once the user clicks on a level it stops working or something else?

Comment: Thank you again for responding! What you are saying is correct that the if statement that is checking if the selectors are pressed is only to be check once. The issue is in the if statement that is above this one. It is supposed to detect if the mouse is within the selector and if so the selector would become larger and lighter to show that you are hovering over it. However, my program checks this once at the beginning and stops so the draw() function immediately covers it up due to the else statement below it.

Comment: It seems that the problem lies elsewhere in the code, then. Ideally, you should look into the minimal, reproductible example I told you about in the first reply and update your post with one, but I am willing to take a look at your code if you post it. I'm afraid it needs to be the whole thing, because the problem isn't in the part you posted so far.

Comment: Ok I will post the full code because I have no clue as to where the problem could be so I think I would have trouble with created a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: [Is this the issue?](https://imgur.com/a/qkDWIwZ) (I don't have the images so don't mind their absence.)

Comment: yes except that its doesn't even do the highlighting once and it stops

Comment: I see what's wrong. I'll update you when I finish work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was harder to diagnose than it looks. As you had guesses, there is a problem in the level selection screen. But the problem is also in the `startScreen()` method, and the symptom you can see, the "freeze", is a consequence of these things in relation with the level selection logic implemented.

It took me some time to see the problem because at first it missed a lot of functions, and even later I still didn't have the images, so I had to tweak the code to see stuff, which made me this half guesswork and half analysis.

You may wonder why I'm saying all these things. There's a good reason: I want you to be able to ask your next question in a manner which will help people to answer it. If you had asked a question about a specific functionality, it would have been easy enough, but this is debugging. To debug code without being to run it is much harder than it could. That's why I told you about posting a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you need help with a bug, being able to reproduce it is a powerful tool for those who willing to help. That I have been the only one to answer may be linked to this deficiency.

---

The problem is `mousePressed`. If you [read a little bit on it](https://processing.org/reference/mousePressed.html) in the the Processing documentation, you'll see this: "The mousePressed variable stores whether or not a mouse button is currently being pressed".

This also means that the `mousePressed` will be true as long as a mouse button is down. The user can click on a random spot, keep the button down and drag the mouse toward a level selector and it will register in your code as if he had clicked on this level.

Here's what happens:

1. In the `startScreen()`, the user clicks on the image to start.
2. The gamestate goes into "level selection" faster than the eye can see, and waaay faster than the finger on the mouse can release the button.
3. The level selector which appears right where the mouse is registers this as a click.
4. The gamestate change to "2", but the level the user choose by mistake isn't available yet. The game seems to freeze because it's stuck there.

As you can see, you have to figure out a way to differentiate "holding a button down" and the user actually clicking on something. For now this is just a small glitch, but as you build on this program it'll become a problem increasingly frustrating.

There are many, many ways to deal with this. I'll give you code for one of them which I think is simple and efficient. Still, if you are ambitious enough, to create a class which only exists to manage the user inputs would be a cleaner and better structured way to do this.

But let's take the easy road for now (step by step for clarity):

1. Add this global variable:

   ```
   boolean leftMouseButtonClicked = false;
   ```

   It will replace the problematic `mousePressed` later.
2. Add this method to your project:

   ```
   void mouseClicked() {
     if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
       leftMouseButtonClicked = true;
     }
   }
   ```

   This will turn on the boolean we added in point 1 when the user click then releases the LEFT mouse button. `mouseClicked` is a built in Processing function. You can [read more about it here](https://processing.org/reference/mousePressed_.html).
3. Change your `draw()` method for this one:

   ```
   void draw () {
     switch (gamestate) {
     case 0:
       startScreen();
       break;
     case 1:
       levelSelection();
       levelSelector1.displaySelector();
       levelSelector2.displaySelector();
       levelSelector3.displaySelector();
       levelSelector4.displaySelector();
       levelSelector5.displaySelector();
       levelSelector6.displaySelector();
       levelSelector7.displaySelector();
       levelSelector8.displaySelector();
       levelSelector9.displaySelector();
       levelSelector10.displaySelector();
       break;
     case 2:
       switch (level) {
       case 1:
         level1();
         break;
       default:
         gamestate = 1;
       }
     }

     leftMouseButtonClicked = false;
   }
   ```

   It's about the same thing, with a couple important changes:

   3.1. I took the liberty of using a `switch` statement instead of the handful of `if` statements there was before. The `switch` is easy to read and the cases need to be mutually exclusives for this to work. You could have used the `if - else if - else if...` form instead, but I like the `switch` better for readability.

   3.2. I added a `default` case to the level switch, so when you misclick on a level which doesn't exist yet instead of freezing it'll go back to the level selection gamestate.

   3.3. I turn off the `leftMouseButtonClicked` boolean so it doesn't stay "on" all the time.
4. Change every place where you wrote `mousePressed` so you use `leftMouseButtonClicked` instead.

That's all there is to do to correct the situation. I tried not to optimize your code so it stays yours (except for those `switch` which I couldn't resist). Your code makes sense and is much better structured than a many others. Sure, it could be improved a lot, but that's the kind of stuff that you'll learn while getting better. And I'm confident that you'll be good.

I hope I made everything clear. Good coding and have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful! Sometimes when I am looking at documentation I see the switch() function and I didn't really understand how it worked. Your explanation has helped me to not only fix the problem but to understand a very useful function! Once again thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it made a difference! Don't forget to "Accept" the answer so someone looking for a similar answer will have an easier time finding this.